# angularJS - xeditable.js

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I would have one questions concerning angularJS xeditable.js:

1. I have the following editable text and I don't want to wrap schedule.startTime and schedule.endTime in a separate span.
   Is there any possibility to configure editable-text that both, schedule.startTime and schedule.endTime can be changed (like editable-text="schedule.startTime & schedule.endTime")

   ```
   < span editable-text="schedule.startTime">{{ schedule.startTime }}-{{ schedule.endTime }}
   ```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: why is using two spans a problem?

Comment: Because I use ng-repeat and there are a lot of DOM- elements in ng-repeat -> therefore I will reduce the html elements.

Comment: This isn't the place to try to reduce DOM elements; if you make the entire `<span>` editable, that means the person editing it could move or remove the `-`, and how is the framework supposed to know where the first variable ends and the second variable begins?